# R timediff - 22-JAN-16 04.56.14.325000000 PM

Tags: r, difftime

I want to calculate the duration between 2 date of a data frame which formatted as per below:

Start_date_time
22-JAN-16 04.56.14.325000000 PM

End_date_time
23-JAN-16 05.56.14.325000000 AM

I run the below command:

```
jm16$diff <- difftime(strptime(jm16$Start_date_time, format = "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M.%S"), 
                      strptime(jm16$End_date_time, format = "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M%S"),
                      units="mins")
```

however, it ends up the entire field of jm16$diff is "NA". Anybody please help to advise where I make mistake?

Thanks

Han

Comment: %Y is for four digit years - you need %y. You will also need to specify the AM/PM with %p

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.    I changed the command to                                                                                               jm16$diff <- difftime(strptime(jm16$Start_date_time, format = "%d-%b-%y %i.%m.%s %p"), strptime(jm16$End_date_time, format = "%d-%b-%y %i.%m.%s %p"),units="mins"), but the result is still the same                                                                                                        > summary(as.numeric(jm16$diff))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
     NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA 1540335

Answer (score 0):

The formula you need to use is:

```
jm16$diff <- difftime(strptime(jm16$End_date_time, format="%d-%b-%Y %I:%M.%OS %p"), 
                      strptime(jm16$Start_date_time, format="%d-%b-%Y %I:%M.%OS %p"), 
                      units="mins")
```

This corrects the following issues:

1. `difftime()` takes `difftime(end_time, start_time)`, not the other way around
2. `%I` deals with hours in 1-12 as opposed to `%H` which deals with 0-23
3. The hour is followed by a colon in your string, not a dot
4. There is a fractional part to the seconds so `%OS`, instead of `%S`
5. A `" %p"` at the end to take in the am/pm

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I tried the formula you gave, but the following error appear: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: Try it for an individual row?

Comment: Ah, and maybe lowercase y's

Comment: I tried the entire field with strptime(jm16$Start_date_time, format = "%d-%b-%Y %I.%M.%OS %p"), it return result as below:       ..........[9913] NA                      NA                      NA                      NA                     
 [9917] "16-01-05 15:12:50 LMT" "16-01-05 15:12:50 LMT" "16-01-05 15:12:50 LMT" NA                     
 [9921] NA                      NA                      NA                      "16-01-05 22:10:20 LMT"
 [9925] "16-01-05 22:10:20 LMT" NA                      NA

Comment: tried again with lower "y"  -   strptime(jm16$Start_date_time, format = "%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%OS %p")   - return result as below: ............[9917] "2016-01-05 15:12:50 SGT" "2016-01-05 15:12:50 SGT" "2016-01-05 15:12:50 SGT" NA                       
 [9921] NA                        NA                        NA                        "2016-01-05 22:10:20 SGT"
 [9925] "2016-01-05 22:10:20 SGT" NA                        NA                        NA

Comment: enter this: jm16$Start_date_time [9920] is the format correct?